# Detailed view of list row

Tags: android, listview, android-view

In my project have to populate the list view from local database.I have implemented it.When I click the row in list item I need to show all the details in list row in next activity.I implemented custom list adapter.I not yet started to code for detailed list row.How can I pass all details in single row to another activity.Can anyone help me?

Comment: what kind of objects/data you would want to pass to detail activity?

Comment: Whats problem just send the object to other activity and populate the list with all the values of the object.

Comment: @Keshav How can I get the object of the selected item?and how can I get the all values of that object in next activity?

Answer (score 0):

one thing that you can do is just pass the id (PK) of the item . Then on next activity you can fetch it again from database.

another options is that you can create a class with all the data you want to forward as class'members and serialize the object and send it along with the intent.

here is a example

```
public class ActivityExtra implements Parcelable {

public Integer a=0;
public String b="";

private GameActivityExtra(Parcel in) {
    this.a = in.readInt();
    this.b = in.readString();
}

public GameActivityExtra() {
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(a);
    dest.writeString(b);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<GameActivityExtra> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<GameActivityExtra>() {
    public GameActivityExtra createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new GameActivityExtra(in);
    }

    public GameActivityExtra[] newArray(int size) {
        return new GameActivityExtra[size];
    }
};
```

}

now create instance of this class in your activity . and use `intent.putextra(...)` to put it . and get the same object while receiving it.

Comment: I am asking how can I pass values in intents?

Comment: How can I pass the Primary Key of item through intent.I am getting the position in onclick method,and how do I find the PM value there

Comment: add a tag to that view and get it in onclick... view.setTag() , view.getTag()

Comment: ,How can I get the primary key value of selected list item

Comment: that i have told you in example . please go through it.. you can create a object of the above class and pass it to intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the information in tags of textviews of your custom list and pass them through intents.

Comment: how can I pass 4 tags in single intent?

Comment: You can do so using different keys. intent.putExtra("key1", textView1.getTag().toString()), intent.putExtra("key2", textView2.getTag().toString())

Answer (score 0):

Use @nitesh goel answer to make your object class parcelabe.

Then onitemclick use

```
 intent.putExtra("object", object);
```

to send your object to other activity.

And in corresponding activity use

```
    intent.getParcelableExtra("object");
```

to get your object. then you can get everything of that object.